# How can i add music settings for my app?? Like Android games

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I have tried android audio manager but it turns off the whole system sound.

Here is my code:

```
if (VolIsMute) {
    manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    VolIsMute = false;
} else {
    manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    VolIsMute = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very simple solution for it

here is my code

```
    Switch aSwitch;
    Button buttonPlay;
    int flag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        aSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.button);

        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sample);

        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    flag = 1;
                }else{
                   flag = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (flag == 0){
                    mp1.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The setStreamMute method was deprecated in API level 23.

You can use adjustStreamVolume with ADJUST_MUTE or ADJUST_UNMUTE instead.

You can find more details here:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html